# Nginx : SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file (..) failed

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I self generated 2 self-signed certificates with openssl for testing purposes using :

```
    $ sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=FR/ST=Charente/L=Mornac/O=Office/CN=api.cockpit.yves" -keyout /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/api.cockpit.yves.key -out /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/api.cockpit.yves.crt
    Generating a 4096 bit RSA private key
    ..........................................................................++
    ...................++
    writing new private key to '/usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/api.cockpit.yves.key'
    -----
    $ sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=FR/ST=Charente/L=Mornac/O=Office/CN=admin.cockpit.yves" -keyout /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/admin.cockpit.yves.key -out /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/admin.cockpit.yves.crt
    Generating a 4096 bit RSA private key
    ..................................................................................................................................................++
    ..............................++
    writing new private key to '/usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/admin.cockpit.yves.key'
    -----
```

and in my nginx.conf file , I set up the Https servers with :

```
server {
    listen       8444 ssl;

    server_name  admin.cockpit.yves;

    ssl_certificate  ssl/admin.cockpit.yves.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/admin.cockpit.yves.crt;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       8445 ssl;

    server_name  api.cockpit.yves;

    ssl_certificate  ssl/api.cockpit.yves.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/api.cockpit.yves.crt;
    ...
}
```

however testing the nginx config, I get the following error :

```
    sudo nginx -t
    nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/admin.cockpit.yves.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)
    nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

what could be wrong ?  is it because I try to setup 2 certificates for 2 different subdomains  (admin. and api. ) for the same domain cockpit.yves ?

thanks for your feedback

Comment: You have the wrong name for your `ssl_certificate_key` file. Cut & paste error?

Comment: thanks that's it... rekey your comment as an answer if you want me to vote for it ...

Comment: I faced the same issue, This can happen when the ssl_certificate_key is not the correct key for the ssl_certificate. Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 12):

Your *key* file probably doesn't contain your *key*.

I had this problem too. In my case, I'd pasted my *crt* in to my *key* file (and my actual *crt* file was correct).

My *key* files begin with the string: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Then ends with the string: `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

*In the comments under the question, Richard Smith actually suggested this as the solution. I'm posting it as an answer to help others later. Props to Richard.*

---

**UPDATE**

I also experienced this message by pasting a combined cert before the cert in the crt file I fed my nginx server.

Comment: I have no clue what you have just told in the update what was the solution what have exactly solved your problem what does this answer actually states

Comment: @Nikoss, this answer basically just teaches us that if we have the wrong contents in our key or crt files, then we can get "SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file" type error messages from nginx.